# Как зафиксировать страницу как вконтакте?

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Кто может подсказать, как зафиксировать страницу по центру, что бы появление скрола не влияло на нее? Пример: вконтакте.ру

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: css 

    position: fixed; 

?

Comment: Повтор вопросов [79543][1], [173583][2]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/79543
  [2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/173583

Answer (score 1):

Ну могли бы зайти в контакт и посмотреть...
К body применяется стиль

```
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

К body нужно применить свойство:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Оно делает скролл всегда видимым, поэтому страница не скачет. А вот `overflow: hidden;` наоборот уберет скролл навсегда, из-за чего пользователь не сможет скролировать страницу.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
```

для того что не должно двигаться.